# MATLAB Tutorial for High School Student with Mediocre Math background

Tags: matlab

I am a **High School** Student who's looking for a **MATLAB** **tutorial** which ***doesn't assume any Math Background*** cause I just **finished my Pre-Calculus** and not really that comfortable with it. I do have a **respectable experience with languages** such as *Python, C++, and Java* so the coding part shouldn't be an issue, I guess. A tutorial in which **both MATLAB and the Math which is used along** is being **thought simultaneously** would really help.

***PS**: I do have an "R2020a" Student License just in case if that somehow is influencing your answer.*

Thank you!

Comment: I am curious what you would need MATLAB for if you don't have a strong math background.

Comment: I am just a curious guy who's trying to learn MATLAB alongside normal Math to make it more intriguing. As said, I do have a decent coding background so it would be an addition to my portfolio.